# Basic authentication session management Domino

Tags: android, rest, session, lotus-domino, basic-authentication

I have a following use case for which I need some pointers/hints/approaches for the solution.

I have to make a login screen for android app following which there will be other screens that would do REST based calls with the server hosted at Domino.

Now for login activity i think that basic authentication seems to be easiest solution (please correct me if i am wrong). The server already has the functionality to support web based application (session based communication which browser handles automatically with domino).

Now the problem part

1. I do not want server to have change its code for the android as server fulfills the requests either for android app OR web based application with the same data. How can I achieve a user scope (i.e. that i can know that subsequent operations are being done by the same user who just logged in successfully via android app) via basic authentication. I suspect Domino does not allow you to access session ID or DOM auth ID which browser intrinsically passes in case of web based application. How can I achieve this functionality from android app ??
2. If I use basic authentication and send the data then i noticed that if i set some session scoped variable during first call PUT, then I do not get that value back while i try to fetch it in next GET call from my android app. I believe the session does not exists anymore between these two calls ?
3. In case of basic authentication, does server needs to do something extra in subsequent calls post successfull login ? for ex: to fetch the list of students in a particular university using REST api, but in order to check if the user is entitled to such an operation server has to know about this user access rights, which in general is stored as a session info in session based authentication procedure.

I understand that in case of basic authentication we pass user id and password with each calls to the server. My main question is that how server handles this user id and password ? does it do some kind of checks each time to check the user permissions for relevant operations ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad set of questions -- on the borderline of being too broad for stackoverflow.  I don't have all the answers, but I think you can solve problem #1 with an Override Session Authentication rule.  For more info, see http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Authenticating_Domino_REST_Service_Requests.  Regarding problem #2, please clarify the question.  REST requests are usually stateless, so I don't know what you mean by, "some session scoped variable".  What session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re this:

> I suspect Domino does not allow you to access session ID or DOM auth
>   ID which browser intrinsically passes in case of web based
>   application. How can I achieve this functionality from android app

Domino just uses cookies to pass the session info back and forth to the client. Depending on which type of session authentication you have set up on the server, it's either **DomAuthSessId** or **LtpaToken**. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003558) for more info.

So I'm going to disagree with you about the presumption that basic authentication is the easiest way to go. If the server is already set up for session authentication, then all you would have to do is make sure that you get the cookie from the response to your login screen and add it to all your HTTP calls and you'll be have your session.

Comment: That said, I agree with what @Dave Delay said in his comment. If you're using a REST API (e.g., Domino Data Service) it should be stateless, and basic authentication is fine for that.

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry if my question went off the hook, but I was able to solve this using exactly what you said. I am using the DomAuthSessId to put in Http header with each subsequent calls, and it works fine. However, I am using for the first time basic authentication from the android app. Do you think I could use some other authentication mechanism too, now since i do not need to send user id password each time to the server, as it just checks for the DomAuthSessId in the http header for subsequent calls !

Comment: I thiink you must already be using session authentication, otherwise the DomAuthSessionId cookie would not exist. So there is no reason to continue sending user id and password with each request.

Comment: Sorry, if i did not make it clear. Yes you are right, i am not sending user id password with each request. However, I am sending it just for the first time using basic authentication. It is working fine, but i was just wondering if there is some other way possible to do the same. I mean without using basic authentication from android

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped. I assumed you must be using Domino session authentication for the first transation. If you are using basic authentication, then I don't think the DomAuthSessionId cookie should exist.

Comment: No, from android i use basic auth for the first login call. However, server handles it in the same way, but i read the http response header in my android app, and i notice that it has the DomAuthSessionId and SessionID in the cookie header. So i pull it out and set it as Cookie header in the next GET call to the server. if for the first time if i do not give it BasicAuth String as Authorzation parameter in HTTP header, I get back 401. That is because server is configured to respond to basic authentication for this particular URL. However, as i said i still see the DomAuthSessionId in theheader

Comment: Interesting. That's a good feature, obviously, but I never knew about it before.